Flutter Android Emulator Errors
I'm working on a mobile app project using Flutter and Dart. I'm now adding Firebase but to help with storing and managing data from multiple users. I did all the setup using Android as my app. However, I seem to get errors during initialization.
Here's the error:
C:\flutter_projects\UHS-StudentTools\android\app\src\debug\AndroidManifest.xml Error:
    uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 19 cannot be smaller than version 21 declared in library [com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:22.0.2] C:\Users\Name\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\8c1b88baa8add63807a0e07d3d434f97\transformed\jetified-firebase-analytics-22.0.2\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 19
    Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 19,
        or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 21,
        or use tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.firebase.firebase_analytics" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 19 cannot be smaller than version 21 declared in library [com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:22.0.2] C:\Users\Name\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\8c1b88baa8add63807a0e07d3d434f97\transformed\jetified-firebase-analytics-22.0.2\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 19
    Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 19,
        or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 21,
        or use tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.firebase.firebase_analytics" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

My build.gradle, where the error occurs:
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.3"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

app/build.gradle:
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

android {
    namespace "com.name.unionville_student_tools"
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.name.unionville_student_tools"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:33.1.2')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:'
}

I've tried changing minSdk from flutter.minSdkVersion to 21. However, this error then occurs.
e: C:/Users/Name/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/3248fbcca8f97a1a99810080888e4df2/transformed/jetified-play-services-measurement-api-22.0.2-api.jar!/META-INF/java.com.google.android.gmscore.integ.client.measurement_api_measurement_api.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
   > Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 8s

┌─ Flutter Fix ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ [!] Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin.                     │
│ Find the latest version on https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html#release-details, then │
│ update C:\flutter_projects\UHS-StudentTools\android\build.gradle:                          │
│ ext.kotlin_version = '<latest-version>'                                                    │
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Okay so let's update Kotlin Gradle by changing ext.kotlin_version = 2.0.10 . Then I get another error
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk...
E/AndroidRuntime(11440): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(11440): Process: com.edisoncai.unionville_student_tools, PID: 11440
E/AndroidRuntime(11440): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.edisoncai.unionville_student_tools/com.edisoncai.unionville_student_tools.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.edisoncai.unionville_student_tools.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~rmTgfNhuyubW5OCKgEcZGQ==/com.edisoncai.unionville_student_tools-Iqt4jnFiG8P_dyu3MMC3yA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~rmTgfNhuyubW5OCKgEcZGQ==/com.edisoncai.unionville_student_tools-Iqt4jnFiG8P_dyu3MMC3yA==/lib/x86_64, /data/app/~~rmTgfNhuyubW5OCKgEcZGQ==/com.edisoncai.unionville_student_tools-Iqt4jnFiG8P_dyu3MMC3yA==/base.apk!/lib/x86_64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
E/AndroidRuntime(11440):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3954)
E/AndroidRuntime(11440):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4235)
E/AndroidRuntime(11440):    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:112)
E/AndroidRuntime(11440):    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeNonLifecycleItem(TransactionExecutor.java:174)
E/AndroidRuntime(11440):    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeTransactionItems(TransactionExecutor.java:109)
E/AndroidRuntime(11440):    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:81)
E/AndroidRuntime(11440):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2636)
E/AndroidRuntime(11440):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
E/AndroidRuntime(11440):    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:232)
E/AndroidRuntime(11440):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:317)
E/AndroidRuntime(11440):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8705)
E/AndroidRuntime(11440):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(11440):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:580)
E/AndroidRuntime(11440):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:886)
E/AndroidRuntime(11440): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.edisoncai.unionville_student_tools.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~rmTgfNhuyubW5OCKgEcZGQ==/com.edisoncai.unionville_student_tools-Iqt4jnFiG8P_dyu3MMC3yA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~rmTgfNhuyubW5OCKgEcZGQ==/com.edisoncai.unionville_student_tools-Iqt4jnFiG8P_dyu3MMC3yA==/lib/x86_64, /data/app/~~rmTgfNhuyubW5OCKgEcZGQ==/com.edisoncai.unionville_student_tools-Iqt4jnFiG8P_dyu3MMC3yA==/base.apk!/lib/x86_64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
E/AndroidRuntime(11440):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:259)
E/AndroidRuntime(11440):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:637)
E/AndroidRuntime(11440):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
E/AndroidRuntime(11440):    at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:95)
E/AndroidRuntime(11440):    at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:45)
E/AndroidRuntime(11440):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1448)
E/AndroidRuntime(11440):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3941)
E/AndroidRuntime(11440):    ... 13 more

So what now?
